# When finding acceleration in a pulley system, why does $ a = (m_1g_1 - m_2g_2)/(m_1 + m_2)$ hold when none of the accelerations is $g$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

[image]

Acceleration (of the system)  is calculated by $$Net.Force/total.mass=a$$
$$(10kg*gravity-5kg*gravity)/(5+10 kg)=a$$
$$(5kg*10m/s^2 )/15kg=3.3 m/s^2$$

Why does this hold?

- the block on the left is not moving down by $10 m/s^2$ as the block on the right reduces the block on the left's acceleration to a value less than $1g$ (and makes the net acceleration upwards not downwards)
- the block on the right is not moving down by 10 m/s^2 as the block on the left reduces the block on the right's acceleration to a value less than $1g$

**So if neither of the acceleration's are equal to $10 m/s^2$, why does our calculation for the net force use the acceleration of gravity?**

Comment: I'm quite confused about what you are asking! The acceleration due to gravity is the force on the system. So we have $\mathbf{F} = 10g-5g=15a$.

Comment: I am confused as to why we take the net force as $10g-5g$. Because when I look at the system, taking the left $5kg$ block for example ... the acceleration on it is not $1g$ downwards as the $10kg$ block on the other side is causing the $5kg$ block to accelerate upwards. Similarly, the $10kg$ block is not accelerating at $1g$ downwards, as the $5kg$ block reduces the acceleration of the $10kg$ block. So with this in mind, I can't understand why the net force is given by $10kg*1g-5kg*1g$, as nothing is accelerating at $g$. Let me know if that still isn't clear.

Comment: well in all dynamical systems such as these there is always a force pointing down which is $m\mathbf{g}$. This is known as weight, and this force is countered with a **normal** force/vector that is pointing is the opposite direction of gravity.  We have a minus sign simply by how we define our axes. So letting the positive $y$ direction be downwards then the forces are $10g - 5g$ and the minus sign is introduced because the first block that weighs $5$kg is being accelerated upwards which is the negative $y$ direction.

Answer (score 3):

It holds because $w=mg$ is a formula for the force called weight, both when the object falls *and* when it doesn't. The $g$ is the acceleration it *would* acquire *if* weight was the *only* force.

If you push hard on a wall, you could also express your pushing force in terms of how fast the wall would move (accelerate), if nothing else held back. You could say "I am pushing so hard that it would move with $5\mathrm{m/s^2}$ if it could". It is another way of expressing or explaining how big a force is.

---

We can agree, I am sure, that weight doesn't change nomatter if it is the only force or not.

Since $w$ has the size of $mg$ when being alone (because $\sum F=ma\Leftrightarrow w=ma$ and this $a$ turns out to be always constant and so is given the name: $g$), it *still* has the size of $mg$ when *not* being alone - because it doesn't change.

Therefore this is called a formula for calculating weight in any situation. If the object actually falls at acceleration $g$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your method works because the gravitational attraction on the masses due to the Earth is independent of the acceleration if the masses ie constant and the string is assumed to be massless and inextensible.

In effect you changed the original problem into the one shown below where $5g$ and $10g$ are constant forces ($g$ is the gravitational field strength) and the total mass is $15 \,\rm kg$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider body of mass *m* near the surface of the earth (Mass - *M* & Radius - *R*). Now gravitational pull on this body due to earth is

$ F = G \frac {Mm} {R^2} $

Now the quantity $ \frac {GM} {R^2} $ is constant near the surface of earth (where we can neglect height of body above the surface compared to *R*). Also it has dimensions of acceleration and multiplying it with mass *m* of body gives gravitational force on that body. So we termed it as *g* - acceleration due to gravity. So now you can see that **acceleration due to gravity has nothing to do with acceleration of body**. It is simply a fixed value which when multiplied by mass gives the value of gravitational pull no matter whatever is the acceleration of body.